# Error with sms outbox query

Tags: android

I am having trouble with querying data from sms outbox with a specific number.
Here's my codes:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
    List<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> numlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String num = cur.getString(2);
        num = num.replace("+639", "09");
        if (!numlist.contains(num)) {
            numlist.add(num);
            inboxmsg.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            inboxmsgdate.add(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));
        } }
        String datafromoutbox=getOutbox(numlist.get(0));
        }



    private String getOutbox(String recipient){
    Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
    Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, "address='"+recipient+"'", null, null);
    cur.moveToNext();
    String d=cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body"));
    return d;
    }
```

The codes above crashes my app. The problem is with the query **"address='"+recipient+"'"** query. But if I change it to **"address='0912344567'"**. If anybody could help me with this.

Comment: Post the stacktrace.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein yup I did it on purpose to show that I have single and double quotes. But with my real codes there are no spaces between them.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein OP updated. :)

Comment: @JoxTraex Stacktrace added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it fixed. I just need to check if the query returns some data.

```
private Data getOutbox(String recipient){
String numsent=recipient.trim();
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/sent");
Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, "address='"+numsent+"'", null, null);
ArrayList<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<Data>();
Data item = new Data();
Data d=null;
if(cur.moveToLast()){
    //do something
}
else{
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

If there is no elements from the the query, you should not be trying to get data from it. Always check the size before processing further.